# Add content into a custom admin module

Tags: admin, controllers, custom, menu

I have create a new item in admin menu, next to System.
My item has two children but when I click in them, appears a blank page. How can I add info or content into this pages?

I added it in my adminhtml.xml and I have a CustomController.php with the next function:

```
public function listAction(){
  $this->loadLayout()
       ->setActiveMenu('mycustomtab')
       ->_tittle($this->__('View'));
  $this->renderLayout();
}
```

I don't know where I should put the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alan Storm's tutorial helped me:
[see Setting up the Admin Controller](http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_hello_world_revisited)